# How to make this container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H4lF.png)

I wan to make this container and I have try it making in container by dividing it in 2 row. After that I divide first row in 3 row again but It was not same design made. So, please help me to make this.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: I have erase my code because it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(20),
                    )),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 20,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            "SIGN UP",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 12, 24, 12),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(16),
                              )),
                          child: Text("Step 1"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                          "To register, fill out the form in the sign-up section above. In order to activate your account, we will send you and activation email that you must confirm"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e. It's great tutorial for `Flutter layout positioning`. Have fun!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 150,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        color: const Color(0xff272830),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          header(),
          const Text(
              'To register, fill out the form in the sign-up section above. In order to activate your account, we will send you an invitation email that you must confirm'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget header() {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
      Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
        ClipOval(
          child: Image.network(
            'https://dt2sdf0db8zob.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/9-Best-Online-Avatars-and-How-to-Make-Your-Own-for-Free-image1-5.png',
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 5),
        Text('SIGN UP'),
      ]),
      SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('Step 1',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of container, you can do it by using Card. Take a look at this example from **https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html**

> ```
> Card(
>         child: Column(
>           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
>           children: <Widget>[
>             const ListTile(
>               leading: Icon(Icons.album),
>               title: Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
>               subtitle: Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
>             ),
>             Row(
>               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
>               children: <Widget>[
>                 TextButton(
>                   child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
>                   onPressed: () {/* ... */},
>                 ),
>                 const SizedBox(width: 8),
>                 TextButton(
>                   child: const Text('LISTEN'),
>                   onPressed: () {/* ... */},
>                 ),
>                 const SizedBox(width: 8),
>               ],
>             ),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
> ```